# Can you make a directory behave like "Program Files" / "Program Files(x86)"?

Tags: windows-7-x64

There are certain applications that cannot be run from anywhere but the Program Files directories (ex `C:\Program Files (x86)`) on Windows 7 Pro.

If I want to install something to another drive (ex `I:\OtherPrograms`), these programs simply don't work.
Is there a way to make other directories behave like the two Program Files directories?

FYI: "Run as Administrator" doesn't work.

Comment: Applications in general are happy to run from whatever directory they live in. In what way are "certain" applications failing for you when run from another directory?

Comment: Not sure that this would help but UNC and removable drives are treated differently form resident disks.
Is "I" a real drive or UNC-mapped path? UNC paths get different security treatment i.e. certain process privileges are different and things like "subst" work differently. Also removable drives behave a bit differently to in terms of code segment loading I believe because you can any moment eject it

Comment: It is a permanent SATAIII SSD.

Comment: I installed 3D Mark Vantage on my I drive through steam and it failed. I installed it in Program Files(x86) and it worked w/out errors.

Comment: Failed in what way, exactly? Be detailed.

Comment: When trying to run the program from steam while installed to the I:\ directory, it would install 4 applications, then the application itself would fail w/ a "Instance of 3DMark Vantage already exists" error message and an "An error occured when initializing 3DMark. Error occured in DLL." error message. When installed to Program Files x86, no error occurred and the application ran w/out error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Limit Permissions**

This sounds more like a problem or bad install that is causing these issues than a security behavior.  In short windows will decide where and what you have execute permissions on by your user level.  When you run as administrator you get full access to do whatever you want (the fact they don't run as admin more likely means something is wrong).

With all of that said you could adjust the user permissions and prevent user's from executing programs in known directories.  So if you got your user to install a background service or run your program as an admin you could change the windows permissions and block them from executing ANYTHING outside of acceptable directories.

If you are the author of the program that you only want to run in a particular directory that would be part of your coding.  You would want to get the application path directory, maybe compare that against your current working directory or the like to tell if the user launched the program from the accepted paths.  You could then code your program to warn the user and shut down.

As far as for just telling windows (You can only run this program if it exists in this path) that can be done through the permissions but it wont necessarily effect future changes.  Example, you can set it so that users can NOT execute in C:\Apps.  But the user may create C:\Apps\Haha after your program manipulated the permissions and execute from there.  The more you run and the less functionality you give the user over their own system the less likely they will use your product so it's not really something you want to do unless you have a really good reason.

**Programs that fail if installed in other locations**

After discussing this a bit more it appears the question originally was how do you fix a program that fails if you install it somewhere outside of the Program Files directory.  In short the answer is you don't, it's not windows or your fault.  The "Program Files" or "Program Files (x86)" directories are only "special" in that the world considers them to be.  As far as the computer is concerned they are just paths on your hard drive.  As far as windows is concerned they are just a path on your hard drive.

The only time things really start getting any different is that windows exposes "Environment Variables" to programs (at the code level).  These Environment Variables are stored and edited in the registry.  One of these pointed out in another post lets you tell windows where your "Program Files" directory is.  Changing this path could cause problems to start occuring in many of your installed programs and is generally not recommended for any reason.

Another thing to note about the "Program Files" directories is that programs can ask windows for it's "Program Files" path.  Windows will check the registry and tell your program what the current "Program Files" paths are.  This is more likely where the problem with your programs is, not the fact that they are installed somewhere besides the program files directory.  It is possible that the coders figured you would install in the program files directory, so when you try to run the program it is looking for a resource in the program files directory but you installed it in whatever custom directory.  The only way to fix this is to do custom installs and pay close attention when it asks you for path's.  You will need to seek documentation for each program to fix it.

**Just a little more about permissions**

Also just for a little more clarification on UAC (User Access Control or Permissions).  They are basically sets of rules based on user accounts on the operating system.  (Windows and PC Users in this case).  When you are using your computer you are logged in to one of these PC User accounts.  Windows will then give you access to directories and files based on the rules set for your user account.

The rules are actually very basic when you break them down.  Rules can apply to directories or files, every directory and file on your system has rules set for it.  In most cases these rules are all set and handled behind the scenes so you may not be aware of them.  These rules separate access based on 3 conditions, for the owner of the file or directory, for the associated group of the directory or file, and everyone else.  That means each "rule" for each directory or file consists of 3 conditions.  Each of these condition's for a rule will then tell us if the user can read, write, execute or any combination of these 3.

So with that said and to apply this to the question, when you install a program you start by executing the installer.  That installer may then try to run as administrator or might ask you to let it go administrator.  From here the installer program starts placing files on your system (wherever you tell it to, it doesn't touch your permissions in most cases).  Once all the files are in place the installer quits and you can start using your program.  At this point, assuming the program works and doesn't have bugs and that the installer program installed everything you need your ready to go.  The only thing that MIGHT be in your way now is that your user permission don't allow you to execute programs in the directory that you just installed in.  Most likely though this won't happen, if you have write you'll have execute permissions.

Now when you do run the program (from anywhere) you are telling windows "Launch this program"  Windows checks the permissions, if you can execute that file or files in that path then it will run the program.  If not it will tell you that you can't and tell you why.  The program starts up and it has all of the exact same permissions that YOU do because you launched it.  If you run as administrator, the program will definitely launch and will be given full permissions to everything (bad idea in most cases).  That's it, there is nothing that would say "If you launch from Program Files make yourself admin"  or "If your in the program files you can edit the system registry keys".  It's all based on permissions of users and "who" launches the program.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I want to GIVE privileges, not restrict them. Also, I'm the user not the developer. There are differences in how programs installed to the two "Program Files" directories behave verses installing the same program to some other directory. This may be due to privileges on the install directory or it may be permissions on some other directory that is written to or read from by certain applications.

Comment: There is nothing that inhibits where you can launch a program from in windows except the permissions that can limit paths and files that certain users CAN execute.  It's not window's fault if a program doesn't work outside of the program files directory.  Probably poor coding design where they forgot to account for a user installing in a custom directory.  So no there's no way to fix this in windows, you would have to figure out why the program isn't running outside of the programs directory.

Comment: Figured it would be best to provide a little more information.  Updated my answer to give some more details about the program files directories and why I can't give you any better answers.  If you are getting specific error messages add those to your question for better results.

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that in order to get around certain UAC issues, programs installed to the default Program Files directories have special access in Win 7. Is it possible to grant write access to `C:\SomeDirectory\ ` to all applications installed under `C:\SomeProgramDirectory\ ` ?

Comment: Programs run as the user who launches the program.  Some programs can install themselves to run as "background" services which are hidden programs that run as the admin (or really any other user that you install it to run as).  But no just the fact that a file resides in the program files does not give it any elevated permissions.

Comment: So basically the developers, most likely, just forgot to populate and use an installationDirectory variable.

Comment: Just edited some more information on permissions that might also be useful.  Can't say for sure without reading error logs and experiencing the problem myself.  But the most likely causes are A a dependency wasn't installed or isn't accessible (some how the install really got messed up) or that the coders missed something and are expecting your install to be in the program files directory.  In both of these cases and without a better knowledge of Windows on the whole I would suggest just install it where it works.

Answer (score 0):

As I know . There is a way you can try. There are some risks.so be careful.

start "run" dialog.
Enter "regedit" and then open regedit editor. locate this  value.

```
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion"
```

in right window,find "ProgramFilesDir"  double click it ,and then modify it's value to your location.then enter. close regedit editor.reboot your pc..

Comment: I don't want to move that directory, I want to create a third directory w/ the same privileges and access.

Comment: That will change the system variable for the program files path.  That will just break more than it would ever fix.

Comment: Sorry...I mistook what you mean..